# Numeric Keyboard not showing on Webview TextBox focus Android

Tags: android, android-webview

Currently I am using `WebView` in my application to load `WebPage`. `WebView` has one `TextBox` which only allows Numeric value to enter.

I have done `JavaScript` validation and restrict user to enter any other character other than Number.

It is working in `WebPage` but when `TextBox` is focused in Android `WebView` then It is not showing Numeric Keyboard.

Instead of that it is showing Simple Keyboard

What can be done to show Numeric Keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set appropriate input type attribute:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved it by specifying

```
<input type="number" />
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" />
```

in Web-form.

Comment: @AzizShaikh as you have mentioned in comments that you need to edit your question so i will create new question regarding general help on writing good questions which would getting better answers and also i have asked for suggestions but some users on meta are downvoting instead of giving suggestion.

Comment: @AzizShaikh btw i have undelted it and will edit soon